# Select multiple value using subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have three tables:

1. **articles**
2. **articleTags**
3. **article_articleTags_Rel**

**articleTags_Rel** table has 2 columns

1. **ArticleID_FK**
2. **TagID_FK**

As you can see the **article_articleTags_Rel** is to make relation between the **articles** and **articleTags**

All I want is to select one row from the **articles** table and and all related tags (multiple values) using sub-query.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this data.

Comment: @Mureinik i don't know how this works and i don't know how the returned data will be (may be the tags will be added as columns?), this is the first time i face this situation, any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: You are looking for a join query, not sub queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
select a.name, b.TagName
from 
  article_articleTags_Rel c
  inner join articles a on a.ID = c.ArticleID_FK
  left outer join articleTags b on b.ID = c.TagID_FK
```

Result:

```
name    TagName
---------------
art A   tag 1
art A   tag 2
art A   tag 3
art B   tag 1
art B   tag 3
art C   tag 1
art C   tag 3
```

sql fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d30f/2

Comment: that's not what i'm looking for. btw Thanks! :)

Comment: What are you looking for? Could you give us a sample of the output you want?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not providing any sample, I guess you need only a brief idea:

```
  SELECT a.*, t.* FROM Articles a
  JOIN article_articleTags_Rel r
  ON a.ArticleID = r.ArticleID_FK
  JOIN articleTags t
  ON t.TagID = r.TagID_FK
```

Comment: that's not what i'm looking for. btw Thanks! :)